# RDD size calculation in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I need to calculate the size of an RDD in Java.

In Scala, it was quite easy and I used the following code:

```
rdd.map(_.getBytes("UTF-8").length.toLong.reduce(_+_)
```

which gives the right size.

In Java, I found this:

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(rdd)
```

However, it returns the wrong size, off by a huge margin. 
How can I correctly estimate the RDD size **in Java?**

In this answer, [How can I find the size of a RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397777/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-rdd) ,

```
rows.apply
```

does not work in Java, because we initialize rows as val in scala and 
rdd.collect() returns Object in Java. So not really applicable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the size of a RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397777/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-rdd)

Comment: @philantrovert please check my edit