# Spark- write 128 MB size parquet files

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame (df) with more than 1 billion rows

```
df.coalesce(5)
.write
.partitionBy("Country", "Date")
.mode("append")
.parquet(datalake_output_path)
```

From the above command I understand only 5 worker nodes in my 100 worker node cluster (spark 2.4.5) will be performing all the tasks. Using coalesce(5) takes the process 7 hours to complete.

Should I try `repartition` instead of `coalesce`?

Is there a more faster/ efficient way to write out 128 MB size parquet files or do I need to first calculate the size of my dataframe to determine how many partitions are required.

For example if the size of my dataframe is 1 GB and spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes = 128MB should I first calculate `No. of partitions required as 1 GB/ 128 MB = approx(8)` and then do repartition(8) or coalesce(8) ?

***The idea is to maximize the size of parquet files in the output at the time of writing and be able to do so quickly (faster).***

Comment: What is the significance of 128MB output file size in your case, sounds as if you this is the maximum file size you can tolerate?

Comment: I just want to avoid the "too many  small files" issue. The property "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes" is set to 128MB and so I want the partitioned files to be as close to 128 MB as possible. For example I would like to have 10 part files of size 128 MB files rather than say 64 part files of size 20 MB

Also I noticed that even if the "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes" is set to 128MB I see files of 200MB, 400MB in the output path. I was expecting spark to pack them into 128MB file but this is related to another issue

Comment: "spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes" is used while reading from files. It can't control output files. For output files, you can use "spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile". If your rows are more or less uniform in length, you can estimate the number of rows that would give your desired size (128MB).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size (`dfSizeDiskMB`) of your dataframe `df` by persisting it and then checking the Storage tab on the Web UI as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485411/1859370). Armed with this information and an estimate of the expected Parquet compression ratio you can then estimate the number of partitions you need to achieve your desired output file partition size e.g.

```
val targetOutputPartitionSizeMB = 128
val parquetCompressionRation = 0.1
val numOutputPartitions = dfSizeDiskMB * parquetCompressionRatio / targetOutputPartitionSizeMB
df.coalesce(numOutputPartitions).write.parquet(path)
```

Note that [`spark.files.maxPartitionBytes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior) is not relevant here as it is:

> The maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when *reading* files.

(Unless `df` is the direct result of reading an input data source with no intermediate dataframes created. More likely the number of partitions for `df` is dictated by `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, being the number of partitions for Spark to use for dataframes created from joins and aggregations).

> Should I try repartition instead of coalesce?

`coalesce` is usually better as it can avoid the shuffle associated with `repartition`, but note the warning in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#coalesce(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) about potentially losing parallelism in the upstream stages depending on your use case.

Comment: So if i want to do it in code it would be something like this `val blockSize= 1024*1024*128
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("dfs.blocksize", blockSize)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("parquet.block.size",blockSize)
df.write.option("parquet.block.size", 128 * 1024 * 1024)
`

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce is better if you are coming from higher no of partitions to lower no. However, if before writing the df, your code isn't doing shuffle , then coalesce will be pushed down to the earliest point possible in DAG.
What you can do is process your df in say 100 partitions or whatever number you seem appropriate and then persist it before writing your df.
Then bring your partitions down to 5 using coalesce and write it. This should probably give you a better performance

Comment: If i want minimum no. of parquet files per partition do you think this is a good idea:-
`df.repartition("Country", "Date")
.write
.partitionBy("Country", "Date")
.mode("append")
.parquet(datalake_output_path)`

Comment: Repartitition controls the partitioning in memory while partitionBy controls it on disk. I guess you should specify the no of partitions in repartitition along with columns to control the no of files